# UI drawed twice in some apps

Tags: virtualbox, vlc, xserver

Some apps (as VLC and most other video players, VirtualBox "New machine" window as shown on the screenshot below) are drawn incorrectly - some elements are drawn multiple times, which makes those applications completely impossible to use.

Except the above, other applications don't have such issues.

Video driver: NVidia
OS: Kubuntu 20.04

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What NVIDIA GPU do you have? And what version of the driver do you have?

Comment: `lspci` returns: `3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 980M] (rev a1)`
I tried few versions of the driver (forgot actual numbers) and got the same.
After switching to Intel driver (with `prime-select`) everything works, but of course 3D acceleration is gone.